# How to render programatically created elements into a component?

Tags: angular

I need to create dynamic `<audio>` tags and control them (`play`, `stop` etc). I have a made a component and a service for this.

The services create `AudioTags`and broadcast an array with the created elements in an observable

```
inteface AudioTag {
 id: string,
 audioElement: HTMLAudioElement
}
```

in my component I get the updates but I am not sure how to render `audioElement` so I can use it.

Comment: One option could be to make use of Renderer - https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2. Renderer service provides APIs to add the element at run time.

Comment: sounds like you're not taking a very angular approach by manually creating HTML elements in a service... instead consider making an AudioTagComponent that takes the needed data to construct your audio element as input and creates the html element via angular templating.

Comment: @user2216584  Thanks that pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: @bryan60 yes you are right. But using an component is (as I see) too much overhead because is my service who takes the "make audio" request from another component who needs the `audio` object to control the audio. I would need to send an recieve too much info while creating the tag and using rendering just takes one subscription and is all done.

Comment: Generally speaking, using a component is the more efficient / performant approach than manually creating DOM elements.  Not sure what the use case here would be to have it be otherwise, hard to tell from the given information why this is the case.

Comment: @bryan60 I have found a better way now. Looks like I was wrong and there is no need to append the audio element into the DOM to use it. Keeping it on my data structure is enough.

About the use case, I have a service that instantiates audio classes. Those classes need different amounts of audio tags and need to control them via a component. If I would create a component for each audio tag then I have to get a hold of the elementRef that is created after an update of my service, then return this info to the service and the service has to again send this reference to my classes. It is too much